# Custom FastScroller android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I implemented the fast scroller with the Section Indexer but the text in the fastScrollPreviewBackgroundRight drawable is being magnified. I would like to achieve something like the image [scroll_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4K1On.png)
This is the magnified image I talk about [current_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAi5j.png)

My styles.xml

```
<style name="GuideFastScroll" parent="Theme">
    <item name="android:fastScrollThumbDrawable">@drawable/scroll_thumb_holo</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollOverlayPosition">atThumb</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollTextColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollPreviewBackgroundRight">@drawable/scroll_scrolling_preview</item>
    <item name="android:fastScrollTrackDrawable">@null</item>
</style>
```

scroll_thumb_holo.xml

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/scroll_active" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/scroll_inactive"/>
```

My Adapter

```
private class ChannelsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GuideChannel> implements SectionIndexer {

    private HashMap<String, Integer> fastScrollChannelMapIndex;
    private String[] fastScrollChannelSections;

    ChannelsAdapter(Context context, ImageViewLoader imageViewLoader, List<GuideChannel> guideChannelPresentationModels) {
        super(context, 0, 0, guideChannelPresentationModels);
        fastScrollChannelMapIndex = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        for(int x=0; x < guideChannelPresentationModels.size(); x++){
            String channelName = guideChannelPresentationModels.get(x).getName();
            if(channelName != null) {
                String channelInScroll=channelName;
                if (channelName.length() <= 0) {
                } else if (channelName.length() <= 3) {
                } else {
                    channelInScroll = channelName.substring(0, 3);
                }
                fastScrollChannelMapIndex.put(channelInScroll.toUpperCase(), x);
            }
        }

        Set<String> sectionIndex = fastScrollChannelMapIndex.keySet();
        ArrayList<String> sectionList = new ArrayList<>(sectionIndex);
        Collections.sort(sectionList);
        fastScrollChannelSections = new String[sectionList.size()];
        sectionList.toArray(fastScrollChannelSections);

    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getSections() {
        return fastScrollChannelSections;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPositionForSection(int sectionIndex) {
        return fastScrollChannelMapIndex.get(fastScrollChannelSections[sectionIndex]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
```

---

Comment: Please add some of your code and what you might have tried to solve this. A screenshot of your current app would be nice as well so we know what 'is magnified' means.

Comment: I updated the post, thanks